# Installing pygtk failed

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygtk

When I was trying to use `pygtk` backend with

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....
....
plt.show()
```

it prompts  `ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.`

So, I did `pip install pygtk`, then error prompts which I have no clue for:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-WPCuyH/pygtk/
```

can someone help?